# Result About Zeta Function Worth Publication?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, journals, riemann-hypothesis, advice

Over the past two years at my high school a friend and myself have been working on a paper about the Riemann Hypothesis.

In this paper we derive several definitions of the zeta function from the Dirichlet representation using only basic algebraic techniques. From these definitions we provide explanations of the geometry of the zeta function curve. We also provide two techniques for finding the approximate locations of the zeros of the zeta function using these definitions by plotting their partial sums.

I have done a lot of research and haven't really found anything like it; but that might not mean anything.

We define the zeta function in terms of the Euler formula

We define the zeta function in terms of hyperbolic functions

and we use these definitions to plot the zeta function's partial sums in various different settings; Cartesian, and parametric.  We show how the zeros can be found in both of these circumstances.

Has this been done before? Are the results worth publishing to  a site like arXiv? It is my first paper and any input would be appreciated.

Comment: UW has several faculty members who do research in number theory, and they might be willing to take a look at an early draft

Comment: How does your method of computation compare with existing methods to find zeroes of the zeta function? If it compares favorably and your result is sufficiently novel it might be worth a shot.

Comment: It is a very good thing to be enthusiastic about such stuff! Yet, as evidently you anticipate, other people have been enthusiastic before you. :) The ideal for you would be to have a serious mathematician willing to talk to you about this who'd help place your ideas in a larger context, and so on.

Comment: did you check https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_zêta_de_Riemann where the main representations and ideas and references about $\zeta(s)$ are explained ?